# How to search for multiple GameObjects with a specific tag in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to search for multiple GameObjects with a specific tag and set them all active at once. I cannot seem to work it.

```
void FindObjects(){

GameObject[] object;
object = GameObject.FindObjectsWithTag("Archived");

object[0].setActive(true);

}
```

Comment: I would consider having your tag objects to be implementing an interface that register/unregister the object to a main container. This way, you can use the container in a fast and simple way, without any searching process.

Answer (score 0):

[GameObject.FindObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) Only finds active GameObjects, which means you don't do anything activating them.

You should use [Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll.html) which finds inactive GameObjects too. But beware, as it also finds loaded assets, not only GameObjects. Something like this would do the trick:

```
Transform[] objs = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<Transform>() as Transform[];
for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++){
if (objs[i].hideFlags == HideFlags.None){
    if (objs[i].gameObject.CompareTag("Archived")){
        objs[i].gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Little detail: If you encounter performance problems (thousands of objects being checked). Try adding the Objects to a List<> when creating them so you can just use the list instead of searching for the objects.

A little other detail, thanks to @derHugo:

> Note that in newer Unity versions there is finally FindObjectsOfType(true) which searches only in the Scene and includes inactive objects!

Comment: Imagine having 1000s of objects in the scene, this could stall for seconds.

Comment: I've been using it with thousand of objects, no stall so far, but I'm gonna add a little edit to it.

Comment: Attention! `Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll` includes that .. **resources** so each and every prefab etc are scanned as well! Note that in newer Unity versions there is finally `FindObjectsOfType<Transform>(true)` which searches only in the Scene and includes inactive objects!

Comment: This may work! If it happens to stall, I will add a loading screen which will display before the search begins.

Comment: @Mintvbz I have edited my answer, derHugo way is better.

Answer (score 0):

```css
int gameObjects;

void Start()
{
    GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    gameObjects += 1;
}

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        gameObjects += 1;
    }
    Debug.Log($"there are {gameObjects} Cubes")
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not ideal. You should at least explain why and how this code answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
void FindObjects()
    {
        GameObject[] objects;
        objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Archived");

        if (objects.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("No game objects are tagged with 'Archived'");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
            {
                objects[i].SetActive(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This wouldn't work. GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag only finds active objects. Check my answer.